# Execute original callback first in ajax when monitoring all ajax calls in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

Am monitoring all the ajax request using below piece of code. But actual callback executes only after my callback.

Is there any way to execute the original callback first and then execute my piece of code.

I do not have control over the original ajax request.but due to some requirements i have to do.

Please suggest if there is any work around.

```
_send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {

    /* Wrap onreadystaechange callback */
    var callback = this.onreadystatechange;
    this.onreadystatechange = function() {             
         if (this.readyState == 4) {

             /* We are in response; do something, like logging or anything you want */

         }    

    }

    _send.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your example? What is the "original callback"?

Comment: I have a tree view, when i expand it makes a ajax  call (do not have control here 3rd party component)  and populates the data, the one which renders the data is original callback. But am trigger the expand event through my code and monitoring the response, once response is arrived again i have to expand the child. Problem here is my code executes before child is getting created.

Comment: Could you add a call to `callback()` within the `if` block? It's still not totally clear what the issue could be without more code.

Comment: Yeah, this works for me. But I don't understand why you're setting `var callback = this.onreadystatechange;`.

Comment: as it stands, this will break code that uses `onreadystatechange` ... I would recommend using `this.addEventListner('readystatechange', function() {})` instead ... then you wont need to save the old callback

Comment: @DrewGaynor that callback is what getting executed for all the ajax response. once that is executed another callabck executes which renders the child.

Comment: `/* We are in response; do something, like logging or anything you want */` ... **anything except an XMLHttpRequest of course**

Comment: @JaromandaX so now old callabck will execute first ?

Comment: oh, right ... no guarantees ... in that case just do `callback.apply(this, arguments)` at the top of your `onreadstatechange`

Comment: @JaromandaX i tried above piece of code, but it didn't work. says apply is not defined. Included inside the `onreadystatechange` function

Comment: if that's the case, then the supplied `callback` is not a `function` - perhaps the code doesn't use the 90's `onreadystatechange` and uses the modern `onload` instead

Comment: @JaromandaX Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to work

```
    _send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
        /* Wrap onreadystaechange callback */
        var callback = typeof this.onreadystatechange == 'function' ? this.onreadystatechange : null;
        this.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (callback) {
                callback.apply(this, arguments);
            }
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
                /* We are in response; do something, like logging or anything you want */
            }    
        }
        _send.apply(this, arguments);
    };
```